# How do I defer delivery of email for less than a minute in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Outlook rules let you defer delivery for a whole number of minutes.  Is there a way to configure Outlook to behave like the popular Gmail extension that delays delivery for exactly 10 seconds?

Comment: Unless you're willing to use VBA to do it, it's not possible.

Comment: @KronoS - any tip for how to do it with VBA? This is a very annoying behaviour when you are brainstorming with team members. 99% of time, the realization that you should not have sent the email comes immediately after clicking on the Send button.

Comment: @ysap see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use VBA, you can do the following:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Const defaultDelayInMinutes As Integer = 0
    Const defaultDelayInSeconds As Integer = 10

    Dim timeToSend As Date
     Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem

     On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

     timeToSend = Now + TimeSerial(0, defaultDelayInMinutes, defaultDelayInSeconds)

     Set mi = Item
     mi.DeferredDeliveryTime = timeToSend
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
     MsgBox "Application_ItemSend: " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

<sup>Note: I haven't had the time to test this fully yet and there may be bugs.  Original idea found [here](http://edd.stefancamilleri.com/2014/03/20/delay-email-sending-in-outlook-like-gmail/).</sup>

Comment: How do you add a VBA script as a rule in Outlook?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro [Use this as a reference](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/) but it appears that is should simply be an option in the Rules Wizard.  There was some mention that Outlook 2013 and 2016 removed the feature by default and you may need to do some registry changes to re-enable.